# Problems folding - resorting to hacks with `StringReplace`

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

I would like to `FoldList` a simple function, with desired output:

```
f[a,b,1]
f[b,c,1]
f[c,a,1]

f[f[a,b,1],f[b,c,1],2]
f[f[b,c,1],f[c,a,1],2]
f[f[c,a,1],f[a,b,1],2]

f[f[f[a,b,1],f[b,c,1],2],f[f[b,c,1],f[c,a,1],2],3]
f[f[f[b,c,1],f[c,a,1],2],f[f[c,a,1],f[a,b,1],2],3]
f[f[f[c,a,1],f[a,b,1],2],f[f[a,b,1],f[b,c,1],2],3]
```

which I can hack with

```
t2[li_] := Take[#, 2] &@RotateLeft[li, #] & /@ Range[0, Length@li - 1];
sf[n_] := "" <> ToString[# - 1] <> "], " <> ToString[# - 2] <> "]" -> 
 "" <> ToString[# - 1] <> "], " <> ToString[#] <> "]" &@n;
nl = ToExpression@With[{string = ToString /@ 
     Rest[FoldList[f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ t2@# &, {a, b, c}, 
     Range@#]]}, Fold[StringReplace, string,
     Flatten[{{"]" -> ", 1]", "1], 1]" -> "1], 2]"}, 
     sf /@ Range[3, #]}, 1]]] &[5];

Column[Column /@ Take[nl, 3]]
```

with huge inefficiencies for large `n` (there is no problem with the `t2` part of the function). All I want to do is add in indexing into the last position of `f[_,_,_]`.

I'd really like to do it with something simple like

```
FoldList[f[#[[1]], #[[2]],#2] & /@ t2@# &, {a, b, c}, Range@3]
```

but I can't use `#2` since `MapThread` gets in the way. I know I am over-complicating things - what is a more sensible way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possibility. Create a helper function:

```
g[l_List,i_] := f[##, i]& @@@ Partition[l, 2, 1, 1]
```

Then, fold this helper function:

```
FoldList[g, {a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {f[a, b, 1], f[b, c, 1], 
>     f[c, a, 1]}, {f[f[a, b, 1], f[b, c, 1], 2], f[f[b, c, 1], f[c, a, 1], 2], 
>     f[f[c, a, 1], f[a, b, 1], 2]}, {f[f[f[a, b, 1], f[b, c, 1], 2], 
>      f[f[b, c, 1], f[c, a, 1], 2], 3], 
>     f[f[f[b, c, 1], f[c, a, 1], 2], f[f[c, a, 1], f[a, b, 1], 2], 3], 
>     f[f[f[c, a, 1], f[a, b, 1], 2], f[f[a, b, 1], f[b, c, 1], 2], 3]}}

Comment: great - much better! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

here is another option, though  it is not as good as the code provided by Carl

```
t3[j_List, l_, m_] := Append[ Take[RotateLeft[j, l], 2], m]
h[p_List, i_ ] :=   f @@@ MapIndexed[  t3[p, #, i] &  , Range[0, 2]]
FoldList[h, {a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3 }]
```